# How to import images/change them on button click?

Tags: javascript

in home page there is 3 images and 2 buttons named next and previous. when next button is clicked the 3 images will changed to next 3 images. total images are 100. then next is clicked new 3 images displays. on third click, only  the last one image will shows. 
on previous button click do reverse. the code is in below , not completed

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Check! 1
    </title>
    <style type="text/css"> 
        #myimage {
    position:absolute;
    left:800;
    top:500;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
#myimage1 {
    position:absolute;
    left:500;
    top:500;
 height: 50px;
width: 50px;
}   
#imageDiv
{
position:static;
top: 50px;
left: 10px;


}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var count=0;    
function image(thisImg) {
var img = document.createElement("IMG");
img.src = "img/"+thisImg;
document.getElementById('imageDiv').appendChild(img);
}
function test()
    { 

        //alert("just checking yaar");
        if(count<4)
        {
        ++count;
        console.log("count",count);
        if(count==1)
        {
            image('44585_Murree-Best-Hill-Station-wallpapers-        pictures_640x320.jpg');
            image('91517_background-painting-used-Main-Menu-screen_640x320.jpg');
            image('gravityflue04-640x320.jpg');
        }
        else if(count==2)
        {
            image('44585_Murree-Best-Hill-Station-wallpapers-pictures_640x320.jpg');
            image('91517_background-painting-used-Main-Menu-screen_640x320.jpg');
            image('gravityflue04-640x320.jpg');

        }
        else if(count==3)
        {
            image('44585_Murree-Best-Hill-Station-wallpapers-pictures_640x320.jpg');
            image('91517_background-painting-used-Main-Menu-screen_640x320.jpg');
            image('gravityflue04-640x320.jpg');
        }
        else if(count==4)
        {

            image('44585_Murree-Best-Hill-Station-wallpapers-pictures_640x320.jpg');
            image('91517_background-painting-used-Main-Menu-screen_640x320.jpg');
            image('gravityflue04-640x320.jpg');
        }
        else 
        { 
            console.log("Invalid Count");
        }
    }
    }
    function test2()
    {

        if(count>0)
        {
        --count;    
        console.log("count",count);
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("Invalid Count");
        }
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="image" id="myimage" value="next" name="next" src="next-button.jpg"   onclick="test()">
    <input type="image" id="myimage1" value="" name="next"  src="111645-glowing-green-neon-icon-media-a-media31-back.png" onclick="test2()">
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  When asking questions here, please provide some code as to what you've tried, what you are having trouble with, etc.

Comment: Or, if there is nothing to provide, don't ask.

Comment: function image(thisImg) {
var img = document.createElement("IMG");
img.src = "img/"+thisImg;
document.getElementById('imageDiv').appendChild(img);
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load the `array` with the names of the images. The number of empty `<img />` tags (in the images `<div />`) dictate how many images display at once. Change the `displayImage` to point to the folder that contains the images.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="previous();">previous</button>
    <div id="images">
        <img />
        <img />
        <img />
    </div>
    <button onclick="next();">next</button>
    <script>
        var imageSources = Array(
            "orderedList0.png", "orderedList1.png", "orderedList2.png",
            "orderedList3.png", "orderedList4.png", "orderedList5.png",
            "orderedList6.png", "orderedList7.png", "orderedList8.png",
            "orderedList9.png");
        var firstImage = 0;
        var increment = document.getElementById("images").children.length;
        displayImages();
        function next() {
            if (firstImage + increment < imageSources.length) {
                firstImage += increment;
            }
            displayImages();
        }
        function previous() {
            if (firstImage - increment >= 0) {
                firstImage -= increment;
            }
            displayImages();
        }
        function displayImages() {
            var imageDiv = document.getElementById("images");
            for (var imageIndex = 0; imageIndex < imageDiv.children.length ; imageIndex++) {
                displayImage(imageDiv.children[imageIndex], imageSources[firstImage + imageIndex])
            }
        }
        function displayImage(image, src) {
            if (src) {
                image.src = "images/" + src;
                image.style.display = "";
            } else {
                image.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the code is fragile. if you add anything to the images `div` that isn't an `img`, the code will break - so you'd need to beef up the code to select images if you want to wrap them in anything (that wasn't provided from your css).  there are functions that allow you to do this...

Comment: personally, i'd prefer the buttons moved one image at a time in either direction - so that the `div` always displayed three images - removing the need to hide `img` tags that aren't required.

Comment: gotta love those flyby downvotes... lol

Comment: hi buddy, i love it.. its working.. but i need to print 100 images. (or more)..  thanks for this n pls help me to do that..

Comment: Glad it works. I don't understand the bit about printing 100 images.  Is that related to this question or is it a new question?  (if so, it would be better to create a new question)

Comment: it is related to this question.. actually i need to display 100(or more)images from a folder by dynamically.. this code only displays for 10. how to add 100 image names to an array.?

Comment: Where are the files?  On your server or the client's machine?  Is it a static set (that the names can be read and incorporated into the HTML once), or is it a dynamic list that needs to be updated in the HTML each time the page is rendered?  What server side scripting engine is available? PHP, ASP, ASP.net, etc. etc?  Is it a public facing site that needs to be cross browser compatible or is it an intranet site, where you can dictate the browser and security policy?  It's kind of more complex than your original question...

Answer (score 2):

That is probably easiest to solve with jQuery.

Here is a solution you can use: http://jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/infinite-carousel-loop.html

And here is the tutorial: http://jqueryfordesigners.com/automatic-infinite-carousel/

Comment: i want to create this in javascript. pls help me..